# Why return a const reference for a basic type? (std::string::operator[])

Tags: c++, oop

The signatures of the operator `std::string::operator[]` are:

```
char& operator[] (size_t pos);
const char& operator[] (size_t pos) const;
```

Why does the const version return `const char&`, and not just `char`?

Comment: Because that way `&s[i] + i == &s[i + 1]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the whole purpose of a `const` object is that it cannot be modified. If a `const` class member, in this case, returns a mutable reference to a character in the string, you could modify it.

Now, as far as `operator[]` goes, it's because you can use the `&` operator to obtain a pointer to it. After all, something like this is fairly common:

```
 auto *foo=&bar[baz];
```

You wouldn't be able to do it with a plain rvalue return type. At least you can get a `const` pointer, in this case.

Comment: The OP asked about `const char&` vs `char` (not `char&`) (i.e., why not `char` for the const overload), right?

Comment: @JamesAdkison Did you miss the `const` member declaration?

Comment: Yes, I almost missed this part, and updated my answer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No, I didn't. I was just saying they are asking why not `char operator[](size_t) const` vs `const char& operator[](size_t) const`.